# access /admin functionality and features for some user groups

Tags: django

My english is not perfect thus the title is confusing. I don't know how to really put what i want to say. Anyway, I have a django 1.11 application that is running well. Wrote admin.py for some apps and a bunch of admin forms overridden. But client said he wants a different way of doing things (instead of admin carrying out the task, everyone registered on the app can). I already have a dashboard for those users and he wants the admin forms to be in that dashboard as opposed to the /admin default dashboard.

I failed to find such a thing in the documentation, I think. But basically, I want some forms to be avalibale, as they are, in the client dashboard? Is that possible?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question but any user with `is_staff` checkbox is ticked can log in to the admin area. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469174/whats-the-difference-between-staff-admin-superuser-in-django) for starters.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk. I know about is_staff but there will be at least 30,000 users and I don't want to make them staff. We have a model that all users will use. Initially, it was supposed to be maintained by a staff member but client said it will be too much work for staff members so let users add info to it. And he wants them to do it from their own dashboard which is already finished. I don't have much time to do what the admin panel already does in the users dashboard, so I was thinking if there is a way to import the forms/features into the users dashboard?

Comment: Well, there is no easy way to replicate admin functionality in your own forms, but there is no harm in making everyone a staff member as long as they don't have access to the models they don't need to (using [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization))