# Django tastypie: User sees no data

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to add authentication to my API, so only authorized people can see the data.

To my resource class I added:

```
authentication = BasicAuthentication()
authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

Then I added a new user using Django admin. He's listed as active and staff. No other permissions have been given.

Now whey I try the resource URL, it asks for credentials.

When I use the new users credentials, I get nothing:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 0}, "objects": []}
```

No objects, nothing. If I login as root, I see all the data.

How do I assign stuff to the user so it can see the resources?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `stuff status` only designates whether the user can log into this admin site.
You should see
[What's the difference between staff, admin, superuser in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469174/whats-the-difference-between-staff-admin-superuser-in-django)

Secondly, Tastypie's DjangoAuthorization checks the permission a user has granted to them on the resource’s model (via django.contrib.auth.models.Permission).
https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html#djangoauthorization

Obviously, the reason of why root can see all the data is that the root is `superuser`.Thus, you can do:

- grant the user superuser;
- grant the user read permission(can change ..) of current resource_model;