# How to use different tables for authentication in django?

Tags: django, authentication

I am from Laravel background and new to django. My concern is how can I use two different tables for authentication in django. For example, admins table for admin authentication and users table for user authentication. Both tables will have column email, password. In laravel, we can use auth guard for this scenario. I want to know how can I implement this in django. I know we can use groups with auth_user table. But I would like to use different tables for user and admin.
I have not tried anything yet about this. I am looking for business logic for this implementation in django. Also any code reference will be great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use different tables, differentiate users by permissions, groups, attributes

> User objects are the core of the authentication system. They typically represent the people interacting with your site and are used to enable things like restricting access, registering user profiles, associating content with creators etc. Only one class of user exists in Django’s authentication framework, i.e., 'superusers' or admin 'staff' users are just user objects with special attributes set, not different classes of user objects.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#user-objects)

`is_staff`, `is_superuser` attributes are described on [User model docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff)

Answer (score 0):

Django has a powerful default authentication and user model that has some important boolean fields:

**1. is_superuser**

**2. is_staff**

**3. is_active**

Django default authentication model use these boolean fields to identify admins, users or inactive users

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469174/whats-the-difference-between-staff-admin-superuser-in-django)

[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/)

also if you want to create separate user models, you should create 2 new classes to authenticate and save users data then change the authentication backends configuration in `settings.py` file.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'myapp.backends.UserBackend',
    'myapp.backends.AdminBackend',
]
```